# how GitHub/Gitlab package registry(gpr) stores data

Tags: github, gitlab, package, devops, cicd

How **github/gitlab package registry** stores data of packages. Are packages will be on a

1- bare git repo,

or they will be on a

2- separate repo (for that package type)

and we have N specific storage for each type of packages.

Ty

gpr supports these packages at this time:
[image: github package registry supported types]
[Github packages](https://docs.github.com/en/packages)

[Gitlab packages](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/package_registry/)

Which approach does github using (left or right or something else) ?
[image]

Comment: What makes you think it has to be either left or right? I'm not sure that either of these is quite correct.

Comment: Im not sure too. I imagined if I wanted to make a gpr, what I would have done. I appreciate correct solution @sytech